# Search fields alignment with Semantic UI

Tags: angularjs, semantic-ui

I have a problem with Semantic UI:
I am building a webpage in which it is possible to cumulate several search fields by clicking on buttons.

My problem comes from aligning search fields when they appear on the screen.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat='searchCriterion in searchCriteria track by $index'>

    <div class="two wide column" ng-if='searchCriterion.type=="crit_1"'>
        <i class="remove icon" ng-click='removeField($index)'></i>Crit 1
    </div>

    <div class="thirteen wide column" ng-if='searchCriterion.type=="crit_1"'>
        <select class="ui fluid selection dropdown" ng- options='comparisonTag.name for comparisonTag in comparisonTags'>
        </select>
        <br>
        <div class="ui labeled fluid input">
            <div class="ui label">for</div>
            <input type="number">
        </div>
   </div>

<div ng-if='searchCriterion.type=="crit_2"'>
    <div class="two wide column">
        <i class="remove icon" ng-click='removeField($index)'></i>Crit 2
    </div>
    <div class="ten wide column">
        <select class="ui fluid selection dropdown" ng-options='alphTag.name for alphTag in alphTags'>
        </select>
        <div class="ui labeled fluid input">
            <div class="ui label">value</div>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CodePen to illustrate my problem:
http://codepen.io/daedalus418/pen/KWJvzB

If you click on "Category 1"> "Crit 1", everything is as aligned as I wish but I repeat ng-if = 'searchCriterion.type == "crit_1"' twice and I would like to avoid that.

If you click on "Category 2"> "Crit 2", I enclose my search criterion in an additional div allowing me to write only once ng-if ... but aligns all content of this additional div on the left.

I would like to get "Crit 1"'s alignment and writing only once the ng-if.
I have tried several writings, to use left aligned as above but I always get the same result.

Would anyone have an idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the markup on any "Crit_X" the same?

Comment: Yes, it is always a div tag.